# Присваивание результата вызова функции

Tags: c, функции

Начинаю осваивать *C* (раньше имел небольшой опыт *C#*), не могу понять как присвоить переменной результат вызова функции. Например:

```
int main()
{
    int x1=signfx();
    printf("%d",x1); 
}
int signfx()
{
    int x=20;
    return x;
}
```

Как `x1` присвоить результат вызова функции `signfx()`?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Как Вы компилируете этот код и что Вас не устроило в нем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в C нет методов, есть функции. Во-вторых, вы должны объявить прототип функции до её использования:

```
int signfx();
int main()
{
    int x1=signfx();
    printf("%d",x1); 
}
int signfx()
{
    int x=20;
    return x;
}
```

Или поместить саму функцию до её первого вызова:

```
int signfx()
{
    int x=20;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int x1=signfx();
    printf("%d",x1); 
}
```

Ну и ещё пара мелочей:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int signfx( void )
{
    int x = 20;
    return x;
}
int main( void )
{
    int x1 = signfx();
    printf( "%d", x1 ); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего согласно стандарту языка C функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
```

Так как в программе используется стандартная функция `ptintf`, то требуется включить заголовок `<stdio.h>`, где эта функция объявлена.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

В этом объявлении в качестве инициализатора используется постфиксное выражение `signfx()`:

```
int x1=signfx();
```

Однако имя `signfx` не определено. Старые компиляторы или новые компиляторы, поддерживающие совместимость со старыми компиляторами, могут компилировать этот код, так как ранее до принятия текущего стандарта компилятор по умолчанию считал, что это имя функции, имеющий тип возвращаемого значения `int`

Однако теперь это не соответствует стандарту языка C, и поэтому компиляторы могут пометить это предложение как ошибочное. Вы должны предварительно объявить это имя как имя функции перед его использованием в программе. Например

```
int signfx( void );
            ^^^^^
```

Обратите внимание, что в качестве параметра используется ключевое слово `Void`. Это означает, что функция не имеет параметров.

Данные два объявления в отличии от языка программирования C++

```
int signfx( void );
int signfx();
```

семантически различны. Первое объявление говорит о том, что функция не имеет параметров, а второе объявление говорит о том, что о параметрах функции ничего не известно, и число и типы параметров будут выведены из вызова этой функции в программе.

С учетом всего сказанного ваша программа будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int signfx( void );

int main(void) 
{
    int x1 = signfx();

    printf( "x1 = %d\n", x1 );

    return 0;
}

int signfx( void )
{
    int x = 20;

    return x;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
x1 = 20
```

Вы могли бы объявить и определить функцию сразу перед ее использованием, поместив ее определение перед функцией `main`. Определение функции является также ее объявлением. Например

```
#include <stdio.h>

int signfx( void )
{
    int x = 20;

    return x;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x1 = signfx();

    printf( "x1 = %d\n", x1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что понятие метод имеет отношение к классам, то есть классы и объекты классов имеют методы. Так как в C нет классов, то в нем нет такого термина, как метод, а используется термин функция.

Comment: Собственно в C++ тоже нет методов, несмотря на наличие классов.

Comment: @alexolut  Метод - это общий термин,  который используется в теории  ООП независимо от языка программирования.